# How to create SUB-menu in “Allure Real Estate Theme for Placester” wordpress theme?

Tags: themes, wordpress-theming, submenu

The below is the menu code used in default theme of "Allure Real Estate Theme for Placester" wordpress theme

```
 `<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="<?php echo @get_permalink(get_page_by_title('About')->ID); ?  

  >">About</a>     

 </li>
 <li><a href="<?php echo @get_permalink(get_page_by_title('Search')->ID); ?

 >">Search</a></li>
 <li><a href="<?php echo @get_permalink(get_page_by_title('Blog')->ID); ?   

 >">Blog</a></li>
 <li><a href="<?php echo @get_permalink(get_page_by_title('Contact')->ID); ?

 >">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="<?php echo @get_permalink(get_page_by_title('Testimonials')->ID);   
 ?">Testimonials</a>`
```

**How to create SUB-menu in any one main menu of above code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about how you can able to fix this sub-menu issue but you can remove the above code and replace with twenty ten nav bar code. That would do everything all you needed.